# Is this sentence correct? Future perfect

Tags: grammar, tenses

I will have finished cleaning the room by the time you come.

What i want to know is if i can use the word "cleaning" in this sentence. I know that when you use future perfect, you need to have a sentence like "i will have finished my homework by the time you come" but the second verb "cleaning" confuses me.

Comment: As many people see the gerund as a verb that takes on the job of a noun, *cleaning* and *homework* both work in your sentence.

Comment: The sentence could be rephrased as _By the time you come, I will have finished [NP]_. So like Yosef Baskin pointed out you could plug in any meaningful NP to get a meaningful sentence.

Comment: As grammatical as  'I finish cleaning my room' (usually unidiomatic without padding). //  'I finished cleaning my room.' //  'I have finished cleaning my room.'  What is special about the future perfect construction?

Comment: Though those who follow CGEL literally will object, it's perfectly fine to think of a gerund clause (or phrase, if you prefer) as a NP. Since direct objects are canonically NPs, when a gerund acts as an object, it's appropriate to label the node as NP. Nonterminal node labels are totally arbitrary, and only visible from above in this case; from below, the node looks like an S.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the word *cleaning*. Here's why. Diagram the sentence this way:

Subject | verb | direct object | adverb phrase.

I | will have finished | cleaning the room | by the time you come.

*Cleaning the room* is the direct object, which in this case is a gerund phrase, a verb acting as a noun and its objects. Think of it like this: I will have finished **what**? The answer is direct object (cleaning the room), modified by the adverb phrase (by the time you come).